# How to get android studio and appcelerator titanium work together

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, android-studio, appcelerator

I Develop apps using appcelerator Titanium , Appcelerator Titanium requires Java JDK 32 bit installed and the Environment variable java_home set to it's path , sometimes i want to do some edits nativley using android studio , but the problem is that android studio requires Java JDK 64 bit installed and the environment Variable JAVA_HOME set to it's location , when i set the environment variable to one of the sdks the program that require the other one crash , So the question is Is there a way to get both working on my pc ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In android studio you can set a specific JDK path by going to

File --> Project Structure

This should let you keep your PATH set to the JDK required for Titanium